# Can dplyr function work connected with SQL server?

Tags: r, sql-server, dplyr, dbplyr

I have a table in SQL server database, and I want to manipulate this table with dbplyr/dplyr in R packages.

```
library(odbc)
library(DBI)
library(tidyverse)

con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                      Driver    = "SQL Server", 
                      Server    = "xx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
                      Database  = "stock",
                      UID       = "userid",
                      PWD       = "userpassword")

startday = 20150101
day = tbl(con, in_schema("dbo", "LogDay"))
```

[image]

I tried this simple dplyr function after connecting to remote database, but only to fail with error messages.

```
day %>% 
  mutate(ovnprofit = ifelse(stockCode == lead(stockCode,1),lead(priceOpen,1)/priceClose, NA)) %>% 
  select(logDate,stockCode, ovnprofit)
```

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

p.s. When I apply dplyr function after transforming 'day' into tibble first, it works. However, I want to apply dplyr function directly, not transforming into tibble because it's to time consuming and memory intensive.

Comment: No, `dplyr` cannot do that. But `dbplyr` likely can.

Comment: That code is applied with dbplyr, but it has the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is most likely with the `lead` function. In R a data set has an ordering, but in SQL datasets are unordered and the order needs to be specified explicitly.

Note that the SQL code in the error message contains:

```sql
LEAD("stockCode", 1.0, NULL) OVER ()
```

That there is nothing in the brackets after the `OVER` suggests to me that SQL expects somethings here.

Two ways you can resolve this:

1. By using `arrange` before the mutate
2. By specifying the `order_by` argument of `lead`

```r
# approach 1:
day %>% 
  arrange(logDate) %>%
  mutate(ovnprofit = ifelse(stockCode == lead(stockCode,1),
                            lead(priceOpen,1)/priceClose,
                            NA)
                     ) %>% 
  select(logDate,stockCode, ovnprofit)

# approach 2:
day %>% 
  mutate(ovnprofit = ifelse(stockCode == lead(stockCode,1, order_by = 'logDate'),
                            lead(priceOpen,1, order_by = 'logDate')/priceClose,
                            NA)
                     ) %>% 
  select(logDate,stockCode, ovnprofit)
```

However, it also looks like you are only wanting to `lead` within each stockCode. This can be done by `group_by`. I would recommend the following:

```r
output = day %>% 
  group_by(stockCode) %>%
  arrange(logDate) %>%
  mutate(next_priceOpen = lead(priceOpen, 1)) %>%
  mutate(ovnprofit = next_priceOpen / priceClose)
  select(logDate,stockCode, ovnprofit)
```

If you view the generated SQL with `show_query(output)` you should see the SQL `OVER` clause similar to the following:

```sql
LEAD(priceOpen, 1.0, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY stockCode ORDER BY logDate)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Simon, now it works great!

Comment: But, it worked perfertly as I intended after changing logDate to stockCode variable (arrange, order_by) in your fist solution

Comment: In your second solution, it worked perfectly as well with no problem in the output, but with this warning message:

ORDER BY is ignored in subqueries without LIMIT
i Do you need to move arrange() later in the pipeline or use window_order() instead?

Comment: For the second solution, you might want to use the `order_by` argument in the `lead` functoin instead of `arrange`.

Comment: I have another problem, Simon, can you check it out?